# Condition from anonimous column mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

tell me how can I apply the condition for the alias "order_status", swears at the wrong column name, I want to finish the condition where order_status like '% Prodact%'

```
   select oh.id_order_head,
           oh.order_name,
           oh.order_name,
           oh.date_recept,
           subj.subject_name,
           cdir.ul_name,
           (select dbo.func_common_get_state_list (oh.id_order_head, 15)) order_status
    from order_head oh
    join
        access_subject subj on oh.id_manager = subj.id_access_subject
    join
        common_ul_directory cdir on oh.id_customer = cdir.id_common_ul_directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to nest this query in a block as follows or use an inline query

Eg:

```
with data
as(
        select oh.id_order_head,
               oh.order_name,
               oh.order_name,
               oh.date_recept,
               subj.subject_name,
               cdir.ul_name,
               (select dbo.func_common_get_state_list (oh.id_order_head, 15)) order_status
        from order_head oh
        join
            access_subject subj on oh.id_manager = subj.id_access_subject
        join
            common_ul_directory cdir on oh.id_customer = cdir.id_common_ul_directory
)
select *
  from data
 where order_status like '%Prodact%'
```